# On changing an image source to the source of another image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Should the following code not work?

```
$('.elastica').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('bigimage').attr('src')= $(this).attr('src');
});
```

It doesn't change a thing on the site.
I've also tried this outputting the image location trough the the other image's id, but it comes up empty (literally ""). When I output the other image's src to a div box with innerHTML for texting, it comes up as undefined.

Either way it won't update bigimage's src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.elastica').click(function(){
    $('#bigimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: you should go jQuery all the way: $('#bigimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));

Comment: Thanks, this was it, I will accept your answer when I'm allowed. I wish I could choose you twice, for the very swift answer! There was only one problem...

$(this).attr('src') is an anchor, which has no src. To fix this, I used $(this).find('img').attr('src');

Comment: Nirmal, you should edit your code so as not to confuse someone who came here looking for the answer. The anchor you are using has not src attribute.

Comment: @serv-bot 22: Your question does not mention what element the click function is applied to. An onclick event can be even applied to an image. I shall leave the answer as long as you don't change the question.

Comment: To refer to the `src` of the `img` element inside the anchor, you can use `$("img", this).attr("src");`. The second parameter `this` will tell jQuery in which context the img element should be searched.

Comment: You're right. I did not specify whether the 'elastica' class applied to images or div boxes.

Also, $("img", this).attr("src"); gets converted to $(this).find('img').attr('src'); by jquery to my understanding; making $(this).find('img').attr('src'); a bit faster. Both are valid and the amount of time spent converting is not even worth considering, so deciding which to use is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('bigimage')` isn't a jQuery object so you cant use jquery function attr on it. You can do it like this:

```
$(document.getElementById('bigimage')).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
```

but you can also use jquery selector engine to get #bigimage:

```
$('#bigimage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
```

Comment: I just figured it out on my own. I was using the anchor, which has no src.

To fix this, I used $(this).find('img').attr('src');